# Want to get posts from category slug

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a project and getting same results in different category slug. Please help what I'm doing wrong here.

```
$act = $_POST['act'];
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 100,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => $act,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'product',
    'taxnomy'          => 'product_cat',
    'post_status'      => 'publish'); 
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
global $product;
global $wpdb;               
foreach ($myposts as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value->ID;
echo '<li class="product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail first grid with-hover add-hover open-on-mobile with-border span3 featured shipping-taxable product-type-simple product-cat-accommodation-durban product-cat-accommodation-battlefields product-cat-battlefields product-cat-comfortable-accommodation-durban product-cat-comfortable-accommodation-battlefields product-cat-durban instock">';
echo '<div class="product-wrapper">';
echo '<a class="thumb" href="'.get_permalink( $id  ).'">';
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($id);
$post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id );
echo '<img src="'.$post_thumbnail_url.'" />';
echo '</a>';
echo '<h3>'.get_the_title( $id ).'</h3>';
echo '</div></li>';

}
```

Comment: what is value of $act here?

Comment: @BhumiShah This is just a category slug.

Comment: i think issue with your slug because code looks okay

Comment: Is this category have child?

Comment: Have used it with static slug.. but no changes in results.

Comment: Nope this is category has not any child

Comment: I think there is some mistakes in $args array..which makes same result in both results.

Comment: The error is most likely here: 'taxnomy'          => 'product_cat' -> Taxonomy is missing an o. Try to comment this line at all to see if it helps.

Comment: @nunorbatista changed and removed taxonomy..but still not helped.

Comment: @deepak do an echo $act; to see what do you have inside, it might be something with the posted data.

Comment: @nunorbatista Yes I did that and it is showing two different category slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$slug = "category-b";
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'tax_query' => array( 
        'relation' => 'AND', 
         array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => $slug 
         ) 
    ), 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

foreach ($the_query->posts as $key => $value) {
     print_r($value->ID); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After careful consideration, I found the root of the problem:

1. The category needs to be an ID, quoting [Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

> Note: The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and
>   not the category name.
>
> Note: The category parameter can be a comma separated list of
>   categories, as the get_posts() function passes the 'category'
>   parameter directly into WP_Query as 'cat'.
>
> Note: The category_name parameter needs to be a string, in this case,
>   the category name.

2. Taxonomy is not well written, is "taxonomy" and not "taxnomy". Also, you can remove it from there as it's not filtering anything.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Here I want to know two things. i) I want to use slug for filtering not id. ii) The formula is working for default posts and categories not for the woocommerce products and category.